# Lucene number of occurrences

Tags: asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net in my Web App.
Everithing works fine, but now i have to show the number of occurrences of my 'searchstring' in every single document of the hits array.
How can i do this? I use usual BooleanQuery.

That is my search:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.Add(QueryParser.Parse(Lquery, "", CurIndexDescritor.GetLangAnalizer()), false,false);
            BooleanQuery.SetMaxClauseCount(int.MaxValue);

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexPath);
            Hits hits = (filter != null) ? searcher.Search(bq, filter) :         searcher.Search(bq);

 for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
        {
            Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
            SearchResultItem MyDb = new SearchResultItem();
            MyDb.key = doc.Get(KeyField);
            MyDb.score = hits.Score(i);
            result.Add(MyDb);
        }
```

Where can i get the number of occurrences?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built in way to do this, as usually this information has little to no meaning. You can use TermFreqVector but it will be slow. Do you still need the score and/or want to order by score?

Comment: It has mining. It is importent for me. I have to make rating of Organisations over the results of my request. Request is consists of Organisations names. Actually, i am going to built new index just over results of my search and then use Term request over it to calculate termFreq, isnt it good idea?

Comment: Can I make score to be not so complex somehow, but just a number of occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want the score back and dont want to order the results using score you could probably build a custom `Similarity` implementation.

I **quickly** tested the following code, and it appears to work fine with TermQueries and PhraseQueries, i didnt test more query types tho. A `PhraseQuery` hit counts as a single occurence.

```
public class OccurenceSimilarity : DefaultSimilarity
{
    public override float Tf(float freq)
    {
        return freq;
    }
    public override float Idf(int docFreq, int numDocs)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override float Coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override float QueryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public override Explanation.IDFExplanation idfExplain(System.Collections.ICollection terms, Searcher searcher)
    {
        return CACHED_IDF_EXPLAIN;
    }
    public override Explanation.IDFExplanation IdfExplain(Term term, Searcher searcher)
    {
        return CACHED_IDF_EXPLAIN;
    }
    public override float SloppyFreq(int distance)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    private static Explanation.IDFExplanation CACHED_IDF_EXPLAIN = new ExplainIt();
    private class ExplainIt : Explanation.IDFExplanation
    {

        public override string Explain()
        {
            return "1";
        }

        public override float GetIdf()
        {
            return 1.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
Similarity.SetDefault(new OccurenceSimilarity());
```